# Невозможно преобразовать "int *" в "int []"

Tags: c++

```
int size = 0;    
int[] dest = new int[size];
```

При данной записи выдаёт ошибку, что невозможно преобразовать "int *" в "int []"
Подскажите как исправить.

Comment: int* dest = new int[size];

Comment: Может ошибка в том, что создавая интовый массив через `new`, вы получаете указатель на начало массива, а не сам массив?

Comment: размер `int size = 0;` - маловат. не хватит.

Comment: Если требуется создать статический массив то используется `int[]` без `new`, для динамического создается указатель `int*` с `new`

Comment: Это же не C#, `int[] dest` тут не работает. `int* dest`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int size = 25; //Размер среднепотолчный! У Вас будет свой.
    int *dest = new int[size];
```

А вот обращаться к указателю можно так, как если бы это был массив:

```
    int size = 25; //Размер среднепотолчный! У Вас будет свой.
    int *dest = new int[size];
    dest[15]=44;
```

. Квадратные же скобки сразу в декларации означают статический массив, которому присвоить указатель на динамический массив нельзя. Статический – это не тот, который со словом static, то есть сохраняется между вызовами функции. Статический массив – это массив с постоянным количеством элементов. Есть ещё массивы: константные, динамические, разреженные, логические и физические. Ну и про освобождение памяти почитайте, чтоб следующим вопросом не задавать утечку.